# Can Google Nest Hub be set to have custom welcome and check-out messages for Airbnb guests?

Tags: smart-home, nest

I'd like to have a Nest Hub give some basic info to guests when they check in, then a reminder the day before check out and on the day of checkout, a little checklist (I'm imagining an actual form with checkboxes that can be checked that sends to the host! but a simple list would be fine too).

Is something like this possible?